# How can I select all elements in the same table column?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is the code that is working:

```
$.each($('#mytable tr'), function (i,o){
    $(o).find('td:eq(13) input').prop("checked", true);
});
```

It first selects the rows, then for each row find the 13th cell, then find the input (check box).

Can I do this with only one selector?

I have tried

```
$('#mytable tr td:eq(13) input').prop("checked", true);
```

but only one checkbox was ticked.

Comment: `$('#mytable tr td:nth-child(12) input')`?

Comment: I tried, it selects nothing (length=0)

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Comment: Sorry It does selects, but a wrong column. It should be `$('#mytable tr td:nth-child(14) input')`. so are you ready to write your answer? be sure to explain why the index being different ;)

Comment: `nth-child` index starts from 1, that is why if you are trying to select `13th td` it corresponds to 14